# Same v-for loop in two different <div>

Tags: vue.js, v-for

I want to put the same `v-for` loop in two different `<div>`. Is there a way to use a `v-for` loop only once?

Here is an example:

```html
<div class="v-for-1">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    blah blah
  </div>
</div>

<div class="v-for-2">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
    blah blah
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What you have there seems like exactly the normal and reasonable way to do it. Is there some specific reason why you want to find another way?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Not long after I studied vue.js, I thought I shouldn't use the same loop twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just move the v-for to a container div and use it multiple times there. In the below example you will create 2 divs with access to the same item.

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index"
     class="parent-v-for">

  <div class="v-for-1">
    {{item}}
  </div>

  <div class="v-for-2">
    {{item}}
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yea. And if you don't want the wrapper div to be rendered just use <template> in stead

Comment: @HenrikClausen Wouldn't that cause some weird render issues with the template being rendered multiple times inside the same component. If I try to create two templates or try to use two root <div> inside the same template vue gives me an error. I have never tried a v-for on a template tag though.

Comment: I often use it in tables where I need double rows. <tbody><template v-for...><tr>....</tr><tr>....</tr></template>  No problem.  This way though the OP will get one loop with 1-2, 1-2, 1-2 not 1,1,1 2,2,2 which he may want.   Then his own suggestion is the best.

Comment: @zoecode not a problem, if you found one of the answers worked please be sure to mark it as the answer for future reference. Good luck!

Comment: @Scornwell I chose one. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you want to achieve but you can do something like this if you want to print two divs in same loop:

```
    <div class="v-for-1">
      <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        <div> blah blah </div>
        <div> blah blah </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad that if that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a component and call it twice:

vFor.vue

```
<div :class="YOUR_CLASS_FROM_PROPS">
 <div v-for="(item, index) in ITEMS_FROM_PROPS" :key="index">
   blah blah
 </div>
</div>
```

and then:

```
<vFor :items="ITEMS" :className="vfor-1" />
<vFor :items="ITEMS" :className="vfor-2" />
```

**OR**

```
<div v-for="(_, i) in [0, 1]" :key="index" :class="v-for`${i}`">
 <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
   blah blah
 </div>
</div>
```