# vue.js - Is there any way to render elements in two different divs using one v-for loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, loops

The goal is to make the output look like this:

```html
<div id="tabs">
    <div id="first">
        <a>tab 1</a>
        <a>tab 2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="second">
        <a>tab 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I'm using this solution (using two v-for loops):

**tabs.js (current)**

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
          tabs: {
              first: [{ name: 'tab1' }, { name: 'tab2' }],
              second: [{ name: 'tab3' }],
          }
        }
    }
    template: `
        <div id="tabs">
            <div id="first">
                <a v-for="tab in tabs.first">{{ tab.name }}</a>
            </div>
            <div id="second">
                <a v-for="tab in tabs.second">{{ tab.name }}</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
}
```

I had an idea to do something like this but it performs more iterations than in the case with two loops:

**tabs.js (idea)**

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
          tabs: {
              test: [
                  { name: 'tab1', category: 'first' },
                  { name: 'tab2', category: 'first' }, 
                  { name: 'tab3', category: 'second' }
              ]
          }
        }
    }
    template: `
        <div id="tabs">
            <div v-for='category in ["first", "second"]' :id='category' :key='category'>
                <template v-for="tab in tabs.test">
                    <a v-if="tab.category === category">{{ tab.name }}</a>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
}
```

I read [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58000937/same-v-for-loop-in-two-different-div) but it contains slightly different solutions, which unfortunately didn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem using more than one `v-for` loops. And there's no problem using nested `v-for` loops.

The problem I see with your current code is that it's not scalable. You're hard-coding the exact values of your tabs in `<template />`(e.g: `first`, `second`).

The main idea here is to loop through tabs and, inside each tab, to loop through each contents, without the `<template>` needing to know what the tab is or how many there are.
So that when you change your tabs to, say...

```js
{
   tab1: [{ name: 'intro'}],
   tab2: [{ name: 'tab2-1' }, { name: 'tab2-2' }],
   tab3: [{ name: 'tab3' }]
}
```

template still works, without needing any change.

---

To achieve this type of flexibility, you need to use a nested `v-for` loop:

```html
<div id="tabs">
  <div v-for="(items, name) in tabs" :key="name" :id="name">
    <a v-for="(item, key) in items" :key="key" v-text="item.name"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    tabs: {
      tab1: [{
        name: 'intro'
      }],
      tab2: [{
        name: 'tab2-1'
      }, {
        name: 'tab2-2'
      }],
      tab3: [{
        name: 'tab3'
      }]
    }
  })
})
```

```css
#tabs a { padding: 3px 7px }
```

```html
<script src="https://v2.vuejs.org/js/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="tabs">
    <div v-for="(links, name) in tabs" :key="name" :id="name">
      <a v-for="(link, key) in links"
         :key="key"
         :href="`#${link.name}`"
         v-text="link.name"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

But I'd take it one step further and change the `tabs` to be an array:

```js
data: () => ({
  tabs: [
    [{ name: 'intro'}],
    [{ name: 'tab1' }, { name: 'tab2' }],
    [{ name: 'tab3' }]
  ]
})
```

And use `:id="'tab-' + name"` on tab divs if you really need those unique ids. (Hint: you don't).

It makes more sense to me.

Comment: Ok I understand, but it refers to a slightly different thing. I think I used some wrong names in my examples. When writing about `tab` I meant exactly `tab-item`. That is, tab in this example is not a group consisting of even smaller elements. As for template I was using it so as not to create additional divs during the v-for loop. Sorry for the wrong elements naming and thank you for your reply.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by *"`tab` is not a group consisting of even smaller elements"*. In what you've shown so far, each `tab` element is an array. Which is exactly that: a group consisting of smaller elements. And my suggestion is not related to that. It's related to the idea your `tabs` should not be an object, but an array of either arrays or objects (your choice) which the `tabs` should loop through. The only difference between the answer you selected as correct and mine is that mine also explains the reason for which you should use this approach/solution.

Comment: @exec: To make this clear: I don't want you to select my answer as correct. I think it's fair you selected Rohit's answer, as he answered faster. What I wanted (and why I added my answer) was for you (and perhaps future users to come) to understand the reasoning behind this solution. Why it's more valuable than others. Happy coding!

Comment: Right, I misinterpreted your answer. As for my previous answer, I meant that the `tabs` array consists of two groups `first` and `second`. They contain tab-items but both of these groups form a single component all the time (that is, the two groups do not contain different tabs, but common ones that form a whole). You seem to have assumed that they are different groups of tabs but it doesn't really matter, because in fact your answer in this case is correct anyway. Sorry for the problem. @tao

Comment: As for your previous comment, right, Rohit's answer is also correct but I came to the conclusion that because of your additional explanations I will mark your answer as accepted. It may be also helpful for other users.

Answer (score 2):

I did not see any harm in using two `v-for` (one for the object keys and another for the array elements) as far as it is all dynamic. You can give a try to this solution by using of [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tabs: {
      first: [{ name: 'tab1' }, { name: 'tab2' }],
      second: [{ name: 'tab3' }],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div id="tabs">
    <div v-for="tab in Object.keys(tabs)" :key="tab" :id="tab">
      <a v-for="tab in tabs[tab]">{{ tab.name }}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @exec1990 No problem  Btw I did not see any much update in his answer .. for me both looks same but yeah it's totally fine. Thanks

Comment: Your answer is correct but after additional thoughts I accepted @tao answer because of the additional explanations. Anyways, thank you very much!

Comment: I think it would be fair to mark your answer as accepted, since you answered faster. I also upvoted your answer. The only thing I'm not fully on board with, in regards to it is: you're limiting your template solution to work only with an object (why not use `v-for`'s elegant flexibility and allow it to also work with an array? - it's already there, thanks to vue). And the second point is you're not explaining why this is a better solution: it's scalable. It works with any amount of tabs, not just with `{first, second}`. Scalability is Vue's secret sauce, IMHO. When possible, preserve it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a computed property being the `.concat` from both and loop for it

```
export default {
    data() {
        tabs: {
            first: [{ name: 'tab1' }, { name: 'tab2' }],
            second: [{ name: 'tab3' }],
        }
    },
    computed: {
       tabsCombined () {
          return this.tabs.first.concat(this.tabs.second)
       }
    },
    template: `
        <div id="tabs">
            <div v-for='category in tabsCombined' :id='category' :key='category'>
                <template v-for="tab in tabs.test">
                    <a v-if='tab.category === category>{{ tab.name }}</a>
                </template>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
}
```

Comment: I see but there will be still more iterations than if you use two v-for loops (it's a similar solution as in tabs.js (idea)). And the goal is to get this result with as few iterations as possible. Anyways thank you for your answer.